# How does the drive swing left and right?

Tags: drivers

[image]

The angle between the bones cannot reflect the front and back, causes the shape key to work abnormally, as the picture shows.

How should this be achieved?

Answer (score 4):

I'm supposing that in rest pose the two bones are straight.

You have to use two different shape keys, the first activated when the angle is positive (i.e. state A) and the second when it's negative (i.e. state C).

In my example there's an automatic weights assignement, without "preserve volume" active.

The shape keys are fully activated when bone's Z rot is 90 degrees,so the driver's expression are:

rotation_euler*0.64 for left

-rotation_euler*0.64 for right.

[image]

Comment: thanks for answer. I don't know how to generate negative angles. I can't find instructions for this. Could you give me a sample file for reference?